# How to compile "portable" pidgin?

Tags: static, compilation, portability, pidgin

i want to compile a portable version of pidgin , and copy it to other machines. my system is centos 6.4 x64 without root privilege.

if i configure it like this

```
./configure --disable-screensaver --disable-gtkspell --disable-vv --disable-meanwhile --disable-avahi --disable-nm --prefix=/usr/tmp/tmp/pidgin-2.10.9-install
```

and copy the compiled code to another machine, pidgin still tries to find plugins from the prefix path, but on another machine,  the path would most probably change, maybe the user would put it into ~/pidgin ,

i searched on google , only found this page [Compiling pidgin as static....](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1185116)   , it involves adding these arguments to configure:

```
--enable-static --disable-shared LDFLAGS=-static
```

tried all of them, but it doesn't work.
configure output [here](http://pastebin.ca/2644550)

pidgin -d > x.txt output [here](http://pastebin.ca/2644558)

edit:
i tried this:

```
setenv LDFLAGS '-static -Wl,-rpath,\$$ORIGIN/../lib'
./configure --disable-screensaver --disable-gtkspell --disable-vv --disable-meanwhile --disable-avahi --disable-nm --prefix=/usr/tmp/tmp/pidgin-2.10.9-install --disable-sm --disable-perl --with-static-prpls=jabber,gg,irc,msn,myspace,mxit,novell,oscar,simple,yahoo,zephyr
```

now i have all the protocols in pidgin preferences window, but i'm missing all the icons , just the same as the above link.

pidgin -d shows mutiple lines of

```
(15:17:52) ui_main: Failed to load the default window icon (48x48px version)!             
(15:17:52) gtkutils: gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file() returned nothing for file /usr/tmp/tmp/pidgin-2.10.9-install/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/pidgin.svg: Failed to open file '/usr/tmp/tmp/pidgin-2.10.9-install/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/pidgin.svg': No such file or directory
```

it seems it still tries to find the icons from the --prefix path given when i ran configure.

Comment: The first reply in your link has the answer; `--enable-static` et al do not link your code to static libraries, it only tells the compiler to make your libraries static.

Comment: just tried it doesn't work. but i found that adding  --with-static-prpls  or  setting LDFLAGS make it work, i'm not sure which.